# Drawing two curves in the same plot with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hello fellows and folks!

I need to draw the following curve. Could you please give me a hand?

[image]

I tried my best the other day but I had serious problems with the labels inside and outside the plot.

Here are the coordinates for train and test:

train: [1.1257,
 0.9836,
 0.9558,
 0.9431,
 0.9359,
 0.931,
 0.9277,
 0.9252,
 0.9233,
 0.9219,
 0.9205,
 0.9197,
 0.9189,
 0.9182,
 0.9177,
 0.9172,
 0.9168,
 0.9165,
 0.9162,
 0.9159,
 0.9157,
 0.9155,
 0.9153,
 0.9152,
 0.915,
 0.9149,
 0.9147,
 0.9146,
 0.9145,
 0.9143,
 0.9143,
 0.9142,
 0.9141,
 0.914,
 0.914,
 0.914,
 0.9139,
 0.9138,
 0.9137,
 0.9137,
 0.9136,
 0.9136,
 0.9136,
 0.9136,
 0.9135,
 0.9134,
 0.9134,
 0.9134,
 0.9133,
 0.9132]

test: [1.1257,
 0.992,
 0.9681,
 0.9579,
 0.9521,
 0.9485,
 0.9457,
 0.9445,
 0.9432,
 0.9424,
 0.9413,
 0.9409,
 0.9409,
 0.9408,
 0.9402,
 0.9397,
 0.94,
 0.9397,
 0.9397,
 0.9392,
 0.9397,
 0.9395,
 0.9393,
 0.9398,
 0.9389,
 0.9394,
 0.9393,
 0.9396,
 0.9394,
 0.9393,
 0.9392,
 0.939,
 0.9389,
 0.9394,
 0.9393,
 0.9385,
 0.939,
 0.9393,
 0.9392,
 0.9395,
 0.9392,
 0.9396,
 0.9394,
 0.9391,
 0.9397,
 0.9393,
 0.9391,
 0.9397,
 0.9392,
 0.9393]

The actual code (an absolute mess):

```
      \begin{tikzpicture} 
     \begin{loglogaxis}[ xlabel={Epochs}, 
                ylabel={RMSE} ] 


   \addplot coordinates { (5,8.312e-02) (17,2.547e-02)  
                  (49,7.407e-03) (129,2.102e-03) 
                  (321,5.874e-04) (769,1.623e-04)
                   (1793,4.442e-05) 
                   (4097,1.207e-05) (9217,3.261e-06) }; 



   \addplot coordinates{  (7,8.472e-02) 
                  (31,3.044e-02)
                  (111,1.022e-02) 
                  (351,3.303e-03) 
                  (1023,1.039e-03)
                  (2815,3.196e-04)
                  (7423,9.658e-05) 
                  (18943,2.873e-05) (47103,8.437e-06) }; 



   \addplot coordinates{ (9,7.881e-02)
     (49,3.243e-02) (209,1.232e-02) 
       (769,4.454e-03) (2561,1.551e-03) 
        (7937,5.236e-04) (23297,1.723e-04) 
          (65537,5.545e-05) (178177,1.751e-05) }; 



   \addplot coordinates{ (11,6.887e-02)
                   (71,3.177e-02)
                   (351,1.341e-02) (1471,5.334e-03)
                 (5503,2.027e-03) (18943,7.415e-04)
                (61183,2.628e-04) 
               (187903,9.063e-05) (553983,3.053e-05) }; 



  \addplot coordinates{ (13,5.755e-02) 
                 (97,2.925e-02) (545,1.351e-02)
                 (2561,5.842e-03) (10625,2.397e-03)
                   (40193,9.414e-04) (141569,3.564e-04)
                 (471041,1.308e-04) (1496065,4.670e-05) }; 

  \legend{$d=2$,$d=3$,$d=4$,$d=5$,$d=6$} \end{loglogaxis} 

  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
 1.1257
 0.992
 0.9681
 0.9579
 0.9521
 0.9485
 0.9457
 0.9445
 0.9432
 0.9424
 0.9413
 0.9409
 0.9409
 0.9408
 0.9402
 0.9397
 0.94
 0.9397
 0.9397
 0.9392
 0.9397
 0.9395
 0.9393
 0.9398
 0.9389
 0.9394
 0.9393
 0.9396
 0.9394
 0.9393
 0.9392
 0.939
 0.9389
 0.9394
 0.9393
 0.9385
 0.939
 0.9393
 0.9392
 0.9395
 0.9392
 0.9396
 0.9394
 0.9391
 0.9397
 0.9393
 0.9391
 0.9397
 0.9392
 0.9393
 };
 \addlegendentry{Validation error} 
  \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
  1.1257
 0.9836
 0.9558
 0.9431
 0.9359
 0.931
 0.9277
 0.9252
 0.9233
 0.9219
 0.9205
 0.9197
 0.9189
 0.9182
 0.9177
 0.9172
 0.9168
 0.9165
 0.9162
 0.9159
 0.9157
 0.9155
 0.9153
 0.9152
 0.915
 0.9149
 0.9147
 0.9146
 0.9145
 0.9143
 0.9143
 0.9142
 0.9141
 0.914
 0.914
 0.914
 0.9139
 0.9138
 0.9137
 0.9137
 0.9136
 0.9136
 0.9136
 0.9136
 0.9135
 0.9134
 0.9134
 0.9134
 0.9133
 0.9132
 };
 \addlegendentry{Train error} 
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The absolute One! One last question: how do you draw the box inside with text “Validation Error” and “Train Error”?

Comment: @naveganteX The legend? Sure.

Comment: The legend, yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: When I compile the whole tex document, it prints the y values with commas instead of a point. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @naveganteX Most likely you have `set thousands separator={,}` somewhere.